# Is it possible to run commands inside other root fs which is mounted in the current system?

Tags: mount

I have a Ubuntu root filesystem (from another system) partition mounted inside my current system (also Ubuntu).

I would like to remove a user from that system. Is it possible to do that, for example, using chroot into that mount point and then running the userdel command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can use chroot.

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
chroot /mnt
deluser <username>
exit
umount /mnt
```

Assuming `/dev/sdb1` is the partition where your secondary system was installed: mount it, and `chroot` its root directory.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do that, for example, using chroot into that mount point and then running the userdel command?

SYN answered how to do it with userdel while I was typing.

Without using `userdel` would take just a few steps:

- Find the UID of the user with `id -u {username}` and check if there are any temp files belonging to that user with

  ```
  find /var /tmp -uid n
  ```
- Delete the user from ...

  ```
  /etc/shadow
  /etc/passwd
  ```
- Not really needed but you could also remove ...

  ```
  /etc/group
  /etc/login.defs
  ```

[man userdel](https://linux.die.net/man/8/userdel) shows these files as related to userdel.